# Backup entire disk in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, backup

I would like to make a backup of the entire HDD disk.

Step-by-step what I'am trying to do:

1) Check storage capacity (that is going to be backupped):

```
df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       455G  157G  275G  37% /
```

2) Mount extra, empty hdd to /mnt/backup/

```
/dev/sdb        294G   63M  279G   1% /mnt/backup
```

3) Run backup (using lzop as the fastest compressor)

```
dd if=/dev/sda1 bs=4M conv=noerror iflag=noatime,nofollow | lzop -1 > /mnt/backup/dev-sda1.lzo
```

But the backup fails with error: `lzop: No space left on device: <stdout>`

The extra hdd being fulled with dev-sda1.lzo. But the original size of /dev/sda1 "157G" is obviously less than available on /dev/sdb "279G". Even without compression.

In /etc/fstab /dev/sda1 being mounted to "/":

```
UUID=8a49b90e-6115-43a6-9702-7620182bbbf5 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
```

Is it possible that "dd" is doing recursive copy of the "/mnt/backup/" folder and this leads to it fail ?

Please, advice

Comment: No. `dd` is reading your raw block device below the filesystem level, so it has no concept of recursion.

Comment: Also, as you are backing up `/dev/sda1` you are going to get 455GB of input data as `dd` has no concept of filesystems, nor of used/unused space - see above.

Comment: Thanks. I see "the puzzle" now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mark Setchell to show me the correct direction.

Finally the solution to create dump of the whole partition without spaces is:

```
dump -0a -z1 -f /mnt/hdd1/dev-sda1.dump.gz /dev/sda1
```

For 157 G partition of Ubuntu 14.04 + development files + database files "dump" takes 45 minutes (on 7200 rpm HDD) and the result file was 80 G (compression level = 1).